# d3 force-directed graph less friction leads to weaker links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Why is it that lowering the friction (i.e. increasing the friction parameter) leads to weaker links in d3.js's force-directed graph?

The code in d3.js is relatively straightforward and implies that the node is moved back toward its previous position with a magnitude proportional to the friction constant:

```
      o.x -= (o.px - (o.px = o.x)) * friction;
      o.y -= (o.py - (o.py = o.y)) * friction;
```

But I can't conceptually see why this would lead to greater distances between linked nodes when the friction parameter is higher. Below is an example from the fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkerpedjiev/akd7dzg6/

High friction parameter:

```
friction = 0.95
```

Distance between nodes:

```
(index):107 35.14850879446412
(index):107 34.77210062116354
(index):107 36.06111990572048
(index):107 36.09670409235906
(index):107 35.152385179015
```

Increasing (decreasing the parameter) the friction leads to closer distances between the nodes:

```
friction = 0.10

(index):107 28.78454446981791
(index):107 29.591866108497356
(index):107 28.645142627737293
(index):107 29.546890048512065
```

Can anyone make a qualitative description of why this is so and if there's a way to work around it so that the link distance remains constant no matter what the friction parameter is?